# How do I completely prevent dragging a webpage horizontally in Android Chrome?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, scroll, hammer.js

Page structure:

```
<body>
<section id="off-right'></section>
<main></main>
</body>
```

The off-right section is initially translated out of view, and I translate it back onto the page on top of `<main>` with HammerJS, when dragging straight left and right, which works fine. The problem is when I touch the screen, start scrolling up or down, and then without taking my finger off, move it to the left. This moves the whole `<main>` left. I want it to just scroll up/down.

Current things I'm doing:

```
body and main are both width: 100%, max-width: 100%, overflow-x: hidden

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

var offset = window.pageXOffset;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if(offset != window.pageXOffset)
            window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset);
    });

var options = {
  dragLockToAxis: true,
  dragBlockHorizontal: true
};
var hammertime = new Hammer(element, options);
hammertime.on("dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight", function(ev){ 
  ev.gesture.preventDefault(); 
  // code for moving #off-right
});
```

I'm looking for a solution that maintains native browser vertical scrolling (so not doing a Hammer dragup/down handler that preventDefault()s and sets window.scrollTo, and figuring out my own physics/timing for continuing scrolling after the user lets go on an up/down swipe).

Comment: I also tried the solution suggested at the end of this article, where you add a parent that also has overflow-x hidden. http://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/